# WPF custom panel scaling to fit window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF custom panel which arranges its child elements in a spiral shape as per my requirements. The problem I am having is to do with scaling of the items when the window is resized - at the moment it does not scale. Can anyone provide a solution? Thanks - Ben

**Custom panel**

```
public class TagPanel : Panel
{
    protected override System.Windows.Size MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size availableSize)
    {
        Size resultSize = new Size(0, 0);

        foreach (UIElement child in Children)
        {
            child.Measure(availableSize);

            resultSize.Width = Math.Max(resultSize.Width, child.DesiredSize.Width);
            resultSize.Height = Math.Max(resultSize.Height, child.DesiredSize.Height);

        }

        resultSize.Width = double.IsPositiveInfinity(availableSize.Width) ?
            resultSize.Width : availableSize.Width;

        resultSize.Height = double.IsPositiveInfinity(availableSize.Height) ?
            resultSize.Height : availableSize.Height;

        return resultSize;

    }

    protected class InnerPos
    {
        public UIElement Element { get; set; }
        public Size Size { get; set; }
    }

    private Point GetSpiralPosition(double theta, Size windowSize)
    {
        double a = 5.0;
        double n = 1.0;

        double r = a * (Math.Pow(theta, 1.0 / n));

        double x = r * Math.Cos(theta);
        double y = r * Math.Sin(theta);

        x += windowSize.Width / 2.0;
        y += windowSize.Height / 2.0;

        return new Point(x,y);

    }

    private Rect CreateRectangleCenteredAtPoint(Point pt, double width, double height)
    {
        return new Rect(new Point(pt.X - (width / 2.0), pt.Y - (height / 2.0)),
            new Size(width, height));

    }

    protected override System.Windows.Size ArrangeOverride(System.Windows.Size finalSize)
    {
        //double startPos = 0.0;

        List<InnerPos> positions = new List<InnerPos>();

        foreach (UIElement ch in Children)
        {
            // If this is the first time
            // we've seen this child, add our transforms

            //if (ch.RenderTransform as TransformGroup == null)
            //{
            //    ch.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0, 0.5);
            //    TransformGroup group = new TransformGroup();
            //    ch.RenderTransform = group;
            //    group.Children.Add(new ScaleTransform());
            //    group.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform());

            //}

            positions.Add(new InnerPos()
            {
                Element = ch,
                Size = ch.DesiredSize

            });
        }

        //double currentTopMax
        List<Rect> alreadyUsedPositions = new List<Rect>();

        foreach (InnerPos child in positions.OrderByDescending(i => i.Size.Width))
        {

            for (double theta = 0.0; theta < 100.0; theta += 0.1)
            {
                Point spiralPos = GetSpiralPosition(theta, finalSize);
                Rect centeredRect = CreateRectangleCenteredAtPoint(spiralPos,
                    child.Element.DesiredSize.Width,
                    child.Element.DesiredSize.Height);

                bool posIsOk = true;
                foreach (Rect existing in alreadyUsedPositions)
                {
                    bool positionClashes = existing.IntersectsWith(centeredRect);
                    if (positionClashes == true)
                    {
                        posIsOk = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (posIsOk)
                {
                    alreadyUsedPositions.Add(centeredRect);

                    child.Element.Arrange(centeredRect);
                    break;
                }


            }

        }

        return finalSize;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` of the `Panel` set to `Stretch` and the `Width`/`Height` to Auto (`double.NaN`)?

It looks like you are passing the `finalSize` into `GetSpiralPosition()`, which is the function where all the true work happens. Without seeing the code to this function it is difficult to say more, but I assume you are calculating correctly off of the `finalSize`.

Have you debugged to see if `Arrange` is getting called with the updated size when the window is resized? There would be two ways to test this: First, put a trace point instead of a breakpoint. Dump `finalSize` to the output window and see if it changes when the window is resized. Second, add a handler in the window to `SizeChanged`. Put a breakpoint in the handler. When the breakpoint is hit, put a breakpoint in the arrange method of the custom panel and then run.

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks for your response - please see the updated code so you can get a clearer picture. Thanks

Comment: Problem is that arrange is not get called with the new size when the window is resized can you assist with this?

Comment: @Ben: Did you check to see if HorizontalAlignment/VerticalAlignment and Width/Height are set up as I mentioned? If you observe a Grid panel, it rearranges it's content when the window is resized.